# Doesn't see records in admin site of django

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I have a problem with one of my tables that I created in my django Project. The recording of data via administration site is very good, but I do not see any record. when I try to see the records in recent actions, I get the following message "*Produit with ID "None" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?*"

---

[Image of django administration site with the warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhXan.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you haven't add 
`MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'`
 to your project's `settings.py` file.